# From the same windows 2012 server can I use multiple gcloud accounts at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are pushing do different buckets in gcp using different gcloud accounts.
Can we push at the same time from the same Windows server using different gcloud accounts?
We are using below to activate the account
gcloud config configurations activate

We were not able to accomplish this

cmd.exe /C gcloud config set account XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.gserviceaccount.com && gsutil ls gs://BUCKET/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you cannot do this using `gsutil` in the manner asked.

`gsutil` shares credentials with `gcloud`. You would have a race condition trying to do this from multiple places (terminals) or processes.

You could do this if you are using separate login accounts on the system as the credentials are stored relative to the user's home directory.

The correct approach is to use one service account that has been granted access to the required buckets via Google Cloud IAM. Then you do not need to switch accounts.

Comment: If in windows we were to use different service accounts (domain\account) and using runas via domain\account + password using the command above , would that also work?

Comment: I am not sure as I have not tried that. However, why do you want to use that method? Assign the correct IAM roles to the service account and be done.

Comment: They want a user only have access to a single bucket for security reasons, I don't have control on that.